# Warning in Sys.junction(from, to) : cannot set reparse point in R

Tags: r, package, reparsepoint

I am using R 3.2x64 and the Development Version of RStudio (0.99) on Windows 8-1 x64. I am not succeeding in performing the R CMD checks of any new package since I have been thrown the following message : "... cannot set reparse point".

Below a more detailed log:

Warning in Sys.junction(from, to) :
  cannot set reparse point 'Z:\Temp\Rtmpugnnnj\RLIBS_b8462e13540/markovchain', reason 'Funzione non corretta'
Error in flink(where, tmplib) : 
  cannot link from C:/Users/Giorgio/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/markovchain
* removing 'F:/GIORGI~1/UNIVER~1/LIFECO~1/LIFECO~1.RCH/lifecontingencies'

The environment is below specified:

ALLUSERSPROFILE C:\ProgramData APPDATA C:\Users\Giorgio\AppData\Roaming asl.log Destination=file CommonProgramFiles C:\Program Files\Common Files CommonProgramFiles(x86) C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files CommonProgramW6432 C:\Program Files\Common Files COMPUTERNAME SPEDYPC ComSpec C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe DISPLAY :0 FP_NO_HOST_CHECK NO GFORTRAN_STDERR_UNIT -1 GFORTRAN_STDOUT_UNIT -1 HOME C:/Users/Giorgio/Documents HOMEDRIVE C: HOMEPATH \Users\Giorgio LOCALAPPDATA C:\Users\Giorgio\AppData\Local LOGONSERVER \SPEDYPC NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS 8 OS Windows_NT PATH C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin\x64;c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin\x64 PATHEXT .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE AMD64 PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER AMD64 Family 21 Model 2 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD PROCESSOR_LEVEL 21 PROCESSOR_REVISION 0200 ProgramData C:\ProgramData ProgramFiles C:\Program Files ProgramFiles(x86) C:\Program Files (x86) ProgramW6432 C:\Program Files PSModulePath C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ PUBLIC C:\Users\Public R_ARCH /x64 R_DOC_DIR C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/doc R_HOME C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0 R_LIBS_USER C:/Users/Giorgio/Documents/R/win-library/3.2 R_USER C:/Users/Giorgio/Documents RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/mathjax-23 RS_LOCAL_PEER \.\pipe\34320-rsession RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/rpostback RS_SHARED_SECRET 63341846741 RSTUDIO 1 RSTUDIO_MSYS_SSH C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/msys-ssh-1000-18 RSTUDIO_PANDOC C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT 34320 RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY Giorgio SESSIONNAME Console SystemDrive C: SystemRoot C:\Windows TEMP Z:\Temp TMP Z:\Temp USERDOMAIN spedyPC USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE spedyPC USERNAME Giorgio USERPROFILE C:\Users\Giorgio windir C:\Windows

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I succeeded by changing:

```
Sys.getenv("R_WIN_NO_JUNCTIONS") #in case the error happens, should be clean
Sys.setenv(R_WIN_NO_JUNCTIONS="Z:/TEMP") #now I set it to may temporary folder
```